# Access html content loaded with jQuery's load() function

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, content-management-system

I'm a bit confused by how jQuery ajax works. I'm trying to create a customer management system (CMS) with jQuery and php.

I want to give the user the opportunity to create a car. Let's say he must define a "car name" and check some options in a checkbox list. 
At the same page i give the user the opportunity to add or delete some options. This adding
and deleting happens with jQuery and ajax. When a user add an option, i call a php page (addOption.php) that processes the option and add's it to the database. If the ajax call is successful, i reload the options in a div using the ajax load() function. Who calls a php page (reloadOptions.php) that reads out the options from the database and constructs them into a list of check-boxes.

All this works fine. The problem occurs when i try to check what check-boxes are checked.
(difficult sentence here )
It seems that the data don't exist in the page source. I think this happens because of the asynchronous working of ajax. And i really need the options to create the car!

Finally, my question is how can i access that options data? And if you can't, is there still
a way where you can access that data?
What do you think about my approach to handle the cms system? Good / Bad / omg / ...

Below are some code blocks i use:

The page index.php : jQuery/ajax that processes the options and the html code

```
 //At the start i load the options in
$('.options').load('./php/OptionsReload.php');

$("#FormOptions").submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/addOption.php",
        data: $(e.target).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $('.options').load('./php/reloadOptions.php');
        }
    });
    return false; 
});

..................
//Form where you can add the option
     <form id="FormOptions">
             <input type="text" name="optionName" />
             <input type="submit" name="submitOption" value="Add option" />
</form>

......................
 //Div where i show the options to the user
      <form name="formChecks" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <div class="options">
                   //Content loaded with jQuery
             </div>
       </form>
```

The page addOption.php : code that adds the option to the database

```
 //Database connect
...
return mysql_query("INSERT INTO options(option) VALUES('". $POST_['optionName'] ."');");
```

The page reloadOptions.php : code that constructs the html with the options

```
<select name="mydropdown">
    <?php 
            $options = ...... connect with DB and select all the options
              while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($options))
               {
                      echo ("<option value='" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['optionName'] . "</option>");
               }
     ?>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance,
Bert

Comment: You were missing two single quotes in the JS code. I edited your post to reflect it. I recommend checking if it works with those two fixed (I haven't checked the logic yet)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I don't understand what you are going for properly but it seems like you just want to get the values of selected options.
Can you try?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.options').click(function() {
        var optionsArray = [];
        $('.options input:checked').each(function() {
            optionsArray.push(this.name);
        });
        // now optionsArray has all your options
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I first editted your JS. (edit on original question)

About your PHP. Where it should be $_POST, you're writing $POST_ in here:

```
return mysql_query("INSERT INTO options(option) VALUES('". $POST_['optionName'] ."');");
```

It should be

```
return mysql_query("INSERT INTO options(option) VALUES('". $_POST['optionName'] ."');");
```

Also, please use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid having any sort of SQLi vulnerabilities.

As for the "checkboxes", you are NOT generating checkboxes, but dropdowns by using a select tag with options. For allowing multiple selections, you can either go ahead and change it into checkboxes (using `<input type="checkbox">`) or add the multiple attribute to your select (`<select name="options[]" multiple="multiple">`). Both will be fine; personally, I prefer checkboxes.

About saving what values were selected. You will have to make a "cache". You can do something like the following:

```
$("#FormOptions").submit(function(e) {
    //if you stick to select>option, then selector should be:
    // $('.options option:selected')
    var savedOptions = $('.options input:checked');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/addOption.php",
        data: { optionName : this.optionName },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var _savedOptions = savedOptions;
            $('.options').load('./php/reloadOptions.php', function () {
                //if you stick to select>option, then selector should be:
                // $('.options option:selected')
                $('.options input:checked').each(function() {
                    for (var i in _savedOptions) {
                        if (_savedOptions[i].value == this.value) {
                            $(this).prop("checked", true);
                        }
                    }
                })
            });
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Please notice in the comments I specified both selectors, for either checkboxes or for select>option

I think that should do the job. However, be careful with XSS vulnerabilities. If you will keep doing it this way, you better use htmlentities when you generate the HTML, like this:

```
<select name="mydropdown" selected="selected">
    <?php 
            $options = ...... connect with DB and select all the options
              while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($options))
               {
                      echo ("<option value='" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . 
                        htmlentities($row['optionName']) . "</option>");
               }
     ?>
</select>
```

If your client is running on utf8, then just add the parameter for it (this is no longer required if you're running on PHP 5.4):

```
htmlentities($someStringInThisCaseOptionName, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, "UTF-8");
```

However, allow me to say your approach of reloading the entire form is not optimal. You need only a single POST request for this: Make the addOption.php script return JSON like this: `{ valueGenerated : "some id"}`. Then proceed by taking the data and just add the option. To do this you will have to make your PHP script [query MySQL to check what ID was generated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) and return just this:

```
echo "{ \"valueGenerated\" : \"$generatedID\" }";
```

Then do something like this on JS side:

```
$("#FormOptions").submit(function(e) {
    var optionName = this.optionName;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/addOption.php",
        data: { optionName : optionName },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var optionValue = data.valueGenerated;
            $('#formChecks select[name="dropdown"]').append(
                "<option value='" + optionValue + "'>" + optionName + "</option>"
            );
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Please denote something: following the code I did, `optionName` must be escaped or it will cause an XSS vulnerability. You can do that from either the PHP side or by doing proper JS instead of the quick append I just showed.

I think it is easier to do it from the PHP side (just use [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)) but then if you ever wanted other clients to use the same web request, they would "suffer" from it. So, ignore the previous JS code and better use:

```
$("#FormOptions").submit(function(e) {
    var optionName = this.optionName;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./php/addOption.php",
        data: { optionName : optionName },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            var optionValue = data.valueGenerated;
            var newOpt = $("<option></option>").val(optionValue).text(optionName);
            $('#formChecks select[name="dropdown"]').append(newOpt);
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```